# Green circle around via in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

I am a newbie in Altium (have some experience with KiCAD) while placing via I am getting a green circle around via, should I be concerned about this if not how to turn this off.
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Turn layers off one-by-one and uncover which layer it is on.

Comment: It seems to tell you exactly what this is at the bottom right of your screen: the top layer courtyard. As such, I'd not recommend disabling that layer, it is very helpful for laying out boards that pass rule checks and can actually be manufactured

Comment: Thank you all I got it, its like an x-ray showing what's beneath the via, possibly to help in layout, but this feature is kinda annoying

Comment: you don't seem to understand altium layers, not what a courtyard is. Both easy to research! This is not an "annoying feature", it's totally normal that you enable and disable layers while working. You really shouldn't disable this one, if there's anything on the top side (and for symmetry reasons, on the bottom, too) in this green area, *you made a mistake*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the clearance around the via on Layer 2 (GND_1 in your design). Notice how it is sitting "on top" of the adjacent green component outline, which is most likely a courtyard (they are separated with fine lines). This suggests that this circular green feature *is not on the same layer* as the green courtyard features. Internal layers are often negative by default, so a solid circle represents the *lack* of copper on that layer. Check your clearance rules - I suspect the distance between one edge of the via and the edge of the circle will match one of them.

[image]

Pressing Shift S will switch to single layer mode, and then click through the layers (or use the +/- keys on your number pad) to figure out which layer has this feature on it.

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful answer, The circle is not the clearance we can separately set clearance rules in Altium and it won't change the green circle. The below layer is a power layer and if i disable it circle turns red showing different plane (VDD) so I understood its just a feature showing layers beneath.

Comment: @VivekGarg I think you may still be missing something here. I am glad you found which layer the feature is on, but we still do not know exactly what it is. It does include some sort of clearance value. There are a number of clearance rules which may apply for via-to-plane. Could you post a screenshot of your clearance rules please? You can add it to your original post.